# Where to add my registration logic when using microservice architecture?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, microservices, spring-cloud

In my microservice architecture project ,it would have oauth service to authenticate the user and the gateway work as the front end api.

My question is where to write the register logic ?

In the oauth service or in the gateway?

**Finally solution:**
I do that in the user service and call from the gateway. Everything seems to work fine！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe best way is to place all authorization logic into library that is shared across microservices via private artifact repository. This library can configuration beans that can be component scanned when this JAR library is on classpath. component scan might be automatic, if you structure your packages wisely. Or you may want to make that scanning or including this shared logic explicit.

This way you might remove OAuth authorization logic duplication, which would otherwise be present.

Of course I am assuming that your microservices are Spring/Java based. If your microservices would vary programming languages, your authorization logic will be duplicated.

BTW, via shared library, you can cover also other cross cutting concerns of your Java/Spring microservices (monitoring, error hangling...). I've seen this working very well for teams working on 20+ microservices.

**EDIT:** Original response container workd "authentication", but I meant "authorization". Sorry for that confusion. "Authentication" should be in OAuth performed by separate dedicated service. This is not cross cutting concern, because there will be only one service accepting crendentials and returning back Oauth token.  The best solution is to use third party OAuth provider, because you don't need to deal with credentials -> less security concerns for you. "Authorization" is cross cutting concern.

Comment: What I think is that all the microservices that need to be authenticated should call a auth service to do the job of authenticate ,not by the dependency jar of  authentication logic. Is that right ?

Comment: Of course if you are using OAuth, there will be service providing/verifying tokens. You understand it correctly that this service will be external. But logic that will call this service (most probably some servlet filer) can be shared across your microservices via shared JAR. Is that clearer now?

Comment: Your answer assumes that all the microservices use the same programming language which is against the microservices best practices.

Comment: OK, so your best practice for microservices is to have each one in different language. From my experience you use right tool for a job. Which will end up having 3-4 languages, but most of the business domain microservices are often in one language (e.g. Java/Python/Node). If it happens to be Java (which appears to be case here), my answer is relevant.

Comment: The spring security act as the filter ,talks to the authenticate service provider and decode the token from the clients.

Answer (score 2):

User registration is a separate [bounded context](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html) so a separate microservice is the best approach. There is a blog post about this [here](http://richardwellum.com/2017/04/authentication-authorization-and-bounded-contexts/).

Authentication is a cross cutting concern that could be handled by the [API Gateway](http://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html). This would free the upstream microservices of this responsibility - their main job is not verifying that a user is who he claims to be.

Authorization should be the responsibility of a dedicated microservice. It could be called by the API Gateway or by individual microservices.

**P.S. My answer assumes that the microservices are not directly accessible from the outside, they can be reached only by the API Gateway.**

Comment: So in your architecture, if authorization is done by APi Gateway, your individual microservice doesn't verify request at all? That sounds like huge security whole in your architecture. To me authorization is cross cussing concern which is performed by HTTP call to authorization service.

Comment: @luboskrnac Why do you think that? The microservices are inside a DMZ and they are not accessible from outside (i.e. they have local IP addresses). Think about a Docker swarm with no exposed ports: you cannot access anything from outside the network that is not exposed.

Comment: This crucial assumption should be explicitly stated in your answer.

Comment: Did you hear saying from security community that most of the breaches are from insiders? Your microservices shouldn't assume that caller is secure.

Comment: @luboskrnac You are correct, I should have added that to my answer.

Comment: I totally accept LU's opinion that we can never assume that the caller is secure.  But, I actually do that in my company's first microservice project of spring cloud .I assumed that all the microservices is protected by the filewall and not exposing to the outside.

Comment: @JacobChan Be carreful about sharing code across microservices, as each microservice should be independently deployable. This means that this situation is not ok:  when you make a modification in one microservice and then you are forced to redeploy all the other microservices.

Comment: @JacobChan Also, my answer does not exclude a separate mechanism of authentication between microservices, i.e. a stateless JWT auth.

Comment: If you use shared JAR library, your microservice is still independently deployable. Have you heard about artifact repository? Maven is artifact repository. Every microserivce on earth is using artifacts from artifact repository. How do you think that all the open source project came from Netflix? Because they were smart and extracted common concerns into shared libraries.

Comment: @luboskrnac it's about incompatible changes, not about the fact that you cannot physically deploy separatelly.

Comment: With your approach, you would need to N authentication mechanisms in N services when there is breaking change. With my approach, single authentication + bump version for N services. I don't take your last argument. Basic thing is to strive for backwards compatibility in authentication service.

Comment: @luboskrnac I don't understand what you mean. My answer tells that only the API Gateway performs authentication (so 1).

Comment: Ou yeah, sorry I forgot about unprotected services. That is just too alien idea for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163869/discussion-between-constantin-galbenu-and-luboskrnac).

Comment: I agreed with Constantin Galbenu .In my current project, just protect the api gateway by authservice by the way of jwt.